# Making a menu with XML and javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, xml, menu

I was considering making a menu using XML and Javascript. But I am not sure, how to. I was thinking something like this
**Menu.xml**

```
<menuroot>
<menu src="house.png" link="index.htm">img</menu>
<menu src="news.png" link="news.htm">img</menu>
<menu link="index.htm">1-3
<submenu link="1.htm"> 1</submenu>
<submenu link="2.htm"> 2</submenu>
<submenu link="3.htm"> 3
<submenu>31</submenu>
<submenu>32</submenu>
</submenu>
</menuroot>
```

All I want is an easy way for people who dont know programming to change the menu.
Is this a smart way of doing this? Should I try something else? Any ideas?
I also know of PHP if thats something I should rather use.

Comment: I personnaly find xml more disturbing than html^^

Comment: It depends upon your need that whether you should use XML here. XML is used when we need to work in API or some generic structure being predefined.
Personally I suggest for menu preparation you can do with HTML itself. Why XML?

Comment: XML because I think it is easier for people who dont know HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the XML and Javascript

```
<p id="Menu"></p>
<script>
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
        myFunction(xhttp);
    }
};
xhttp.open("GET", "Menu.xml", true);
xhttp.send();

function myFunction(xml) {
    var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
    document.getElementById("Menu").innerHTML =
    xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("menu")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
}
</script>
```

Comment: But this does not work for three levels in the menu?
I have a <ul><il>-menu.

Answer (score 0):

use the PHP function simplexml_load_file which will turn the XML into an object [more..](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php)

```
<?php
$Menu = simplexml_load_file('menu.xml');
echo $Menu->item[0]->itemurl;
?
```

Comment: Is it simple to print out in <ul><il>-menu for three levels?

Comment: yes you can use ul li menu like  <ul><?php foreach($menu as $m){ ?><li><?php echo $m; ?></li><?php } ?></ul>